# Table structure for validating data using category and subcategory fields

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, check-constraints, data-validation

I am creating a simple budget application, and the primary table will be a transaction table that contains things like the amount of the transaction, date, account, the category and subcategory (the type of transaction it was).

A spending category might be "Entertainment" or "Food" or "Household" and each would be further subdivided into subcategories.  The "Food" category might have "Work Lunch", "Grocery Store", "Fast Food", etc. subcategories, for example.

One way to do this is to have a table `Categories`:

```
    id    category     subcategory
----------------------------------
     1        Food      Work Lunch
     2        Food       Fast Food
     3        Food   Grocery Store
     4   Household        Mortgage
     5   Household         Repairs
```

and so on.  I then reference this `id` field in my table `Transaction`, using `type` as a foreign key:

```
id    txdate  amount   type   account   ...
-------------------------------------------
 1   6/25/15  15.25       2      cash   ... (a fast food expense)
```

The problem with this is that I'd like to be able to allow for `null` subcategories, and that doesn't seem to fit that well with this model.

Another way would be to just put the `category` and `subcategory` into the main `Transaction` table:

```
id    txdate  amount   category   subcategory   account   ...
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1   6/25/15   15.25       Food     Fast Food      cash                     ...
```

I have considered using `CHECK` `CONSTRAINT`s but this gets too bulky and messy too quickly, and does not allow me an easy way to access the allowable fields from my front-end code.  I will be validating data in the front end but I would like a robust way to ensure data validation on the actual database update as well, so I thought it would be convenient to store the values in a table (or more than one table), and then retrieve these allowable values in the code.

Any solution will work, but this is such a basic thing that I'm sure some best practices exist for this, and I'd like to query you all to find out what those would be.

Thank you for your time and expertise!

Comment: What about having a generic record for each subcategory  like `0 --- Food ---- Food` that in normal condition is hidden (with hidden as an attribute) , but when choosing `NULL` become  <available> (you know to put the right `Id`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different strategies you could take, where on one end you pursue aggressive normalization to, on the other end, full denormalization.  The full denormalization would be equivalent to your second example where all relevant info simply ends up in the transaction table without references to other tables.

**Full Normalization**

So, to completely normalize, you would still want a `Categories` table, but you want to even eliminate the storage of redundant information in this table, so you would need a `CategoryList` table and a `SubCategoryList` table as

**`CategoryList`**

```
id    category     
----------------
 1     Food      
 2     Household
 etc...
```

and

**`SubCategoryList`**

```
id    subcategory     
----------------
 1     Work Lunch    
 2     Fast Food
 3     Grocery Store
 4     Mortgage
 5     Repairs
 etc...
```

You could then construct your category table from these two tables  as

**`Categories`**

```
id    category_id     subcategory_id
----------------------------------
 1        1               1
 2        1               2
 3        1               3
 4        2               4
 5        2               5
```

Treatment of `NULL` subcategories can easily be handled by either 1) simply placing a NULL entry for the `subcategory_id` column in the appropriate row of the `Categories` table, or 2) adding a subcategory entry `id, subcategory` where the subcategory field is `NULL`.

Last but not least you would add a foreigh key reference from your `Transactions` table to the appropriate `id` in the `Categories` table.

**Does it really need to be so normalized?**

Well, in my opinion, no it doesn't.  I've heard a quote, though I can't remember who spoke it, but it basically goes "Normalize until it hurts, denormailize until it works."  Especially in the case where you don't have a lot of categories, the fully normalized design may be a little bit of overkill.

What might simply make more sense would be to keep the above mentioned `CategoryList` and `SubCategoryList` tables to enumerate your types, but skip making the separate `Categories` table, and then simply have your `Transactions` table referencing the `CategoryList` and `SubCategoryList` tables as

```
id    txdate  amount   category   subcategory   account   ...
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1   6/25/15   15.25      1             2        cash                     ...
```

This way, you save on storage, and you can easily update/modify any category or subcategory entry in the list without needing to modify your entire `Transactions` table.  Further, you can simply permit the `subcategory` column of the `Transactions` table to permit `NULL` entries, if need be.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Chris, thanks so much for your detailed reply.  Regarding your last suggestion, it would seem I almost need the separate Categories table, because otherwise I have no way to link a category and subcategory.  For example, with the ability to enter any category and subcategory id in the primary Transactions table, one could enter a category of "Food" and a subcategory of "Mortgage," and I also would have no way to determine this relationship from my front-end code.  Thanks again for your suggestions, I upvoted you but it may not show as this is my first post on the site.